Jetpack compose. Animation duration is incorrect on some devices
I'm using Animatable to implement linear progress animation.
Here is my code:
 val progress = remember(currStory) { Animatable(0f) }

 progress.animateTo(
                        targetValue = 1f,
                        animationSpec = tween(
                            durationMillis = 5000,
                            easing = LinearEasing
                        )
                    )

LinearProgressIndicator(
        backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
        color = progressColor,
        modifier = modifier,
        progress = progress.value
    )

Everything works well, however on some devices I noticed one problem. Despite the fact that the progress duration is specified as 5000, it is completed in one millisecond. That is, the Animatable value goes from 0f to 1f immediately. What could be the problem?
Help me please)
P.S. also I have tried:
durationMillis = 5000 * (1f - progress.value)).toInt()

P.S.2 If in the developer settings you change the animation speed parameter from 0 to 2, then the animation works correctly

Compose animations honor the Developer Options for animation speed - do those devices have their animation speed set to 0 (i.e., instantly complete)?

You call animate on every recomposition, as in answer below start them in a LaunchedEffect and use currStory as key of LaunchedEffect to restart animation. You don't need to create new Animatable every time your key changes

@Thracian, I'm using LaunchEffect and still have this problem ?

@ianhanniballake, Yes, you are right, in the developer options the animation was 0. But how can I influence this in my code?

Your code should not care what animation speed is set. Why do you think you should care?

@ianhanniballake, I'm trying to implement swiping stories like instagram, and my stories instantly automatically swipe instead of showing the amount of time I set. I find this behavior incorrect and would like to correct it.

You can do it like this,
val progress = remember { Animatable(0f) }

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    progress.animateTo(
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = tween(
            durationMillis = 5000,
            easing = LinearEasing
        )
    )
}

LinearProgressIndicator(
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    color = progressColor,
    modifier = modifier,
    progress = progress.value
)

